# Value of variable is not changing on first iteration when input in loop, batch file

Tags: batch-file

by input the value of variable is not changing, but on next iteration , its show the previous input value.

```
set /a firstNum=0
set /a secondNum=0
:while
if %firstNum% NEQ -99 (
    set /p firstNum="Enter first number"
    echo first number is %firstNum%
)
if %secondNum% NEQ -99 (
    :2input
    set /p secondNum="Enter second Numer"
    echo second number is %secondNum%
    if %secondNum% == 0  ( goto :2input )
)
goto :while
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you want to achieve with this peace of nonsense but if you want your values to chenge you have to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the beginning of your code and call your variables as `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.

Comment: sorry bro next time i will try to ask you first "may i share my code here or not?"
but thanks , it works